# Users cannot login if their Microsoft Account is an Azure AD Account

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, adal

We are using Microsoft Account Authentication on our website. We have implemented the v2 endpoint thinking that would allow anyone with a Microsoft Account to register and login to our site.

However some users report that when they try to login to our site using their MSA, the Microsoft login page is telling them they cannot authenticate as their MSA is a school/work account and they are directed to create another MSA (using Outlook.com).

My apologies that I am not able to offer exact details of the user experience as I am trying to relate the issue as it is reported by our users to our helpdesk.

Microsoft Account Authentication works for many of our users so I assume we are setup correctly. `Startup.Auth.cs` looks like this:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
    }
});
app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

var mo = new MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions
{
    ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Microsoft.Account.ApplicationId"],
    ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Microsoft.Account.ApplicationSecret"],
};
mo.Scope.Add("wl.emails");

app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(mo);
```

The app is setup in the App Registration Portal under Converged appplications. Allow Implicit Flow and Live SDK support are both selected.

Is it the case that if an MSA is a school/work account then that MSA cannot be also used for Microsoft Account Authentication on our site? Or have I done something wrong?

Comment: Do you want to make your app supports  both Microsoft accounts and Azure Active Directory account ? You could try openid connect :https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-v2

Comment: This is where is gets a bit confusing for us and our users @Nan Yu - MSFT. Our users are not corporate users. They are individuals. Some of them think they have a MSA but when they try to login to our site the Microsoft login screen tells them they are using an Azure AD account. Until that point they had no idea their MSA was an Azure AD account. Is it because some of these users also subscribe to Office 365 or some other Microsoft service? Are you saying that for these users to login to our site using their MSA the sample you refer to will work for us?

Comment: @Nan Yu - MSFT The GitHub sample you refer to is different from the one referred to in the current documentation. [Add sign-in to an .NET MVC web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-dotnet-web). Is the current documentation incorrect?

Comment: What is the detail error message when using not working MSA ? and what is the MSA like ? xxx@outlook.com or some other personal microsoft account ?

Comment: @Nan Yu - MSFT Our users are small businesses. They often have their own domain so their email is of the form xxx@mydomain.com. If they already have an MSA using that email, some of our users are being told they cannot login with a work/school account. If they try to create an MSA using that email the error is You can’t sign up here with a work or school email address.

Comment: please confirm whether "xxx@mydomain.com" account is a AAD account(usually like XXXX@tenant.onmicrosoft.com) and implements the custom domain?

Comment: Sorry @Nan Yu - MSFT but I don't understand. How do I confirm if the account is a AAD account? All we know is the email address the user gives us to correspond with them xxx@somedomain.com. As far as the user knows they do not have an AAD account, but that doesn't mean it is not an AAD account. Our users don't understand such things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138606/discussion-between-nan-yu-msft-and-vague).